How to calculate average days of spend return with single arrayformula
In my Google Sheet (see my example sheet here), I have 2 tabs, a Main tab which lists names in A3:A, and a Data Tab in which the names appear somewhere in B1:1, and three columns of data under each name, named SPEND, INCOME, and MISC. A3:A contains Dates in ascending order.
The SPEND columns contain random amounts spent on certain days for each name. The INCOME columns contain random income amounts received on certain days for each name. The MISC columns are for other unrelated data.

On Main Tab, I am trying to figure out how to write a single arrayformula for cell B2 that will calculate the average number of days it takes for each name listed in A2:A to reach their amount spent with their received income.

The only applicable spends for each name are the ones that appear after the first row in which their income is greater than 0, and if the last spend amount has not yet been reached by the income, it is not included in the average either.
The closest I was able to get to this solution was this formula in E3 dragged down to get the average number of days for a specific name (see the Testing Tab in my example): =IF(B3<>"",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SUMIF(ROW(C3:C28),"<="&ROW(C3:C28),C3:C28)>=B3,0),0),"") but it isn't starting at the correct row and I am unsure of how to put this into an arrayformula.

What is the best way to accomplish what I am looking for?

I revised my solution according to suit your needs. As you can see in the image below, I Have only two sheets namely, Main Tab in which we make the calculations and Data Tab which houses the data for the persons listed in the other tab.
You only need to insert the following formula in cell B2 of the Main Tab and will get the results for the names listed in column A
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(PERSON,AVERAGE(LET(HEADERS, 'Data Tab'!$1:$1, myDATA,BYROW(LET(columnSPEND, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(PERSON,HEADERS,FALSE),4),1,""),INDIRECT("'Data Tab'!" & columnSPEND & 3 & ":" & columnSPEND)),LAMBDA(Ø,LET(columnINCOME, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(PERSON,HEADERS,FALSE)+1,4),1,""),futureINCOME, INDIRECT("'Data Tab'!" & columnINCOME & ROW(Ø) & ":" & columnINCOME), IF(AND(Ø>0,OFFSET(Ø,0,1)>0,SUM(futureINCOME)>Ø),COUNT(SCAN(Ø,futureINCOME, LAMBDA(acc,val,IF(acc-val>0,acc-val,""))))+1,"")))), FILTER(myDATA,ISNUMBER(myDATA)))))),"")

.


Thank you, this helped a lot. Unfortunately I get a calculation limit error when trying to use this with large amounts of data, but I don't know if there is an easy fix for that so I am making do with helper columns for now and the formulas you provided.

In your sample sheet, activate sheet named Testing Tab and after clearing the contents in Column E, enter the below single formula in cell E3 as seen in the image below;
=BYROW(B3:B,LAMBDA(Ø,IF(AND(Ø>0,OFFSET(Ø,0,1)>0,SUM(INDIRECT("C" & ROW(Ø) & ":C"))>Ø),COUNT(SCAN(Ø,INDIRECT("C" & ROW(Ø) & ":C"), LAMBDA(acc,val,IF(acc-val>0,acc-val,""))))+1,"")))

Then, you can calculate the averages...
.


Thank you for this, I was able to make this work for columns B and C on the Main Tab, but am stuck figuring out how to make B and C dynamic based on the names in A2:A: =AVERAGE(FILTER(BYROW('Data Tab'!B3:B,LAMBDA(Ø,IF(AND(Ø>0,OFFSET(Ø,0,1)>0,SUM(INDIRECT("'Data Tab'!C"&ROW(Ø)&":C"))>Ø),COUNT(SCAN(Ø,INDIRECT("'Data Tab'!C"&ROW(Ø)&":C"),LAMBDA(acc,val,IF(acc-val>0,acc-val,""))))+1,""))),BYROW('Data Tab'!B3:B,LAMBDA(Ø,IF(AND(Ø>0,OFFSET(Ø,0,1)>0,SUM(INDIRECT("'Data Tab'!C"&ROW(Ø)&":C"))>Ø),COUNT(SCAN(Ø,INDIRECT("'Data Tab'!C"&ROW(Ø)&":C"),LAMBDA(acc,val,IF(acc-val>0,acc-val,""))))+1,"")))<>""))

Use LET and INDIRECT i don't have time to work on now...
